# Change detection in Angular template expression calls function too many times

Tags: angular, date, data-binding, angular2-changedetection

I have dates all throughout my angular application that look something like this:

```
{{ stringAsDate(entry.followUpDate) | date:"yMdjm" }}
```

the stringAsDate function looks like:

```
stringAsDate(dateStr: any) {
    if(dateStr != null){
        return new Date(moment(dateStr).seconds(0).milliseconds(0).toISOString());
    }
}
```

The stringAsDate() function is necessary to have the same dates across all browsers. (I was getting inconsistencies because different browsers evaluate new Date() differently.) Anyways, this works. However, stringAsDate() is getting called every change detection (every click, etc.) so the performance of the application is really bad because I have these dates all over the place.

Is there a way to avoid stringAsDate() being called so many times?

Comment: I'd recommend you to not call a function like that in template. You can just do it in component before passing this variable to template... or maybe create a pure `pipe`. Btw, is this inside a `*ngFor`?

Comment: Have you looked into [OnPush](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html) change detection strategy? It is supposed to improve performance but is also required to be implemented carefully.. it's a bit of a danger zone. Using the OnPush strategy gives you more power over when and where the change detection is being fired and which components it should be checked for changes.

Answer (score -1):

In Angular4 put the ***get*** keyword in the function declaration before its name, so that you'll be able to refer that function in the template as a property (within curly braces).

Comment: Then I get the error "A 'get' accessor cannot have parameters."

Comment: @KevinQuiring, then I would suggest you doing some refactoring. Can you move the dateStr parameter to your component class and initialize it once during Component construction or in the ngOnInit method?